# Basic programming in java-Leap Year

Tags: java

So for a basic programming class, we have to make a program that tells if a year is a leap year. We aren't using the scanner method; rather, the year will be an argument. We have to use a boolean called isLaeapYear(int year). Here is my code

```
public class LeapYear{
  public static void main(String[ ] args){
    int year = readInt();
     boolean isLeapYear(int year) = ((year %4 == 0) && (year % 100 !=0) || (year % 400 == 0));
    if (isLeapYear)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }


  }
}
```

For some reason, it won't compile it says that a ; is expected after isLeapYear in my boolean line. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Are you attempting to declare a `boolean` variable named `isLeapYear` or a method named `isLeapYear` that returns a `boolean`?

Comment: having (int year) after isLeapYear is invalid. Remove it and it should work

Comment: I believe I am supposed to implement a method

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean isLeapYear(int year) = ((year %4 == 0) && (year % 100 !=0) || (year % 400 == 0));
```

The above line makes no sense at all. Do you want it to be a method?

If so it should be:

```
private static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    return ((year %4 == 0) && (year % 100 !=0) || (year % 400 == 0));
}
```

and you would call it like so:

```
boolean isLeapYear = isLeapYear(year); //note that the fact that both the boolean
                                       //variable and the method name are 
                                       //identical is coincidence; the variable
                                       //can be named whatever you want (as long
                                       //as it makes sense).
```

or you can just do:

```
if(isLeapYear(year)) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Or if you just want a `boolean` variable:

```
boolean isLeapYear = ((year %4 == 0) && (year % 100 !=0) || (year % 400 == 0));
```

Comment: It says that 
private boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
is an illegal start of expression

Comment: @user2744756 Add `static` to the definition, since you're calling it from a `static` method.

Comment: It still says it is invalid even with the static

Comment: What is the exact error? Also, you're going to have to figure out some things by yourself. Compilation errors are pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your code should sort of look like (not tested):

```
public class LeapYear{
  //main method (always runs when you compile then run)
  public static void main(String[ ] args){
    //int year = readInt();
    int hardCodedYear = 4;
    System.out.prinln(isLeapYear(hardCodedYear));//method call and print results
  }

  //create method 
  public boolean isLeapYear(int year){
    //check if its leap year (not sure if this is correct)
    if (year %4 == 0) && (year % 100 !=0) || (year % 400 ==0){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got a basic syntax error here. Either isLeapYear is a either a function or a variable, and you are mixing the two. You should have something like

```
boolean isLeapYear = ((year %4 == 0) && (year % 100 !=0) || (year % 400 == 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the code should be like this -

```
public class Leapyr
{
    boolean isLeapYear(int year)
    {
        if((year%4==0) && (year%100!=0) || (year%400==0))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static void main (int y)
    {
        Leapyr yr=new Leapyr();
        boolean rslt;
        rslt=yr.isLeapYear(y);
        if(rslt==true)
        {
            System.out.println("Year is Leap Year");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Year is not a Leap Year");
        }
    }
}
```

when you initiate the `main()` it works properly. I've tested it myself.